# How does one initiate ground combat in StarDrive?

Tags: stardrive

I've been unable to discover how to initiate ground combat. My only luck so far at securing artifacts has been to colonize a planet and build troops on it, but I feel confident that's not the only way. Do I need assault shuttles or transports in order to land troops on a planet and secure an artifact or initiate ground combat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a planet where you have troops, right-click the troops in the map window to send them into orbit in assault shuttles.

Those shuttles are generated for free, but have no defenses whatsoever, so don't send them unescorted if you don't already rule the orbitals.

Send the shuttles to the target planet, then once they're in orbit open the planet's combat view (select planet in galaxy map, click the lower button). You can then deploy your troops to the surface from the ground troops tab.

Comment: Thanks! Here I was building worthless heavy fighters with assault shuttle bays.

Comment: Launch them from carriers and you'll have a marvelous Matroska going on. :)

Comment: Considering I managed to crash by having 9 fleets of 50 carrier cruisers of 9 fighter bays of heavy fighters each with 3 missile launchers, I'll hold off on doing any more Matroskas with carriers. ;)